# Crystal report sorting by custom date

Tags: sorting, date, crystal-reports

I'm having a doubt in how to sort a chart by custom date in Crystal Reports.

My Sql returns this for exemple:

```
Date
2013 Set
2013 Set
2013 Out
2013 Nov
```

I get this value using Decode, the code is above

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM S.sol_datachega) || ' ' || decode(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM S.sol_datachega),1,'Jan',2,'Fev',3,'Mar',4,'Abr',5,'Mai',6,'Jun',7,'Jul',8,'Ago',9,'Set',10,'Out',11,'Nov',12,'Dez') as mes
```

But x axis in my crystal reports sort by the string, so the chart comes like this:

```
2013 Nov
2013 Out
2013 Set
```

If i take the decode off the chart comes right

```
2013 09
2013 10
2013 11
```

But i need it with the name of the month instead of number.

I believe i can do this using formulas but i don't know how to do it because i'm new in crystal reports.

Any idea?

Comment: I wouldn't do the conversion on the SQL level. Bring in your data as it is and then do the conversion by using a formula in CR. That way the data will get sorted correctly in the first place.

Comment: But the data comes with day and i don't want to show the day, just months, is that possible? It's Date in my DB.

Comment: Of course, you just create a formula that takes the date and then transforms it to show what you want. It is very similar to your SQL formula: Year({date.field}), or Month({date.field})

Comment: But this way the x axis will group by month as it's now?

Comment: It shouldn't. It should group by the date value, not the text value.

Comment: To do it i have to select in my change of i need to choose my formula right? And my formula i have to put something like this ?  {Solicitacoes.Mes} = Year({Solicitacoes.Mes}) || ' ' || Month({Solicitacoes.Mes})

Comment: Yes, you choose your formula. The formula to show Year, Month should be like: Year({Solicitacoes.Mes}) & " " & Month({Solicitacoes.Mes}). Name the formula whatever you want.

Comment: But i need to associate this Year({Solicitacoes.Mes}) & " " & Month({Solicitacoes.Mes}) to my value ? like           {Solicitacoes.Mes} = Year({Solicitacoes.Mes}) & " " & Month({Solicitacoes.Mes})

Comment: I did this way Year({Solicitacoes.Mes}) & " " & MonthName (Month({Solicitacoes.Mes})) , now it comes 2.013,00 novembro 2.013,00 outubro 2.013,00 setembro  , but the same way it's coming with no sorting, is there any way to put sort in my formula ?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some testing myself, it seems that there are limitations to what you are trying to achieve. Ken Hamady has an excellent write-up on the ways and limitations to formatting chart dates. Please see his write-up [here](http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/1174) and hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Hi, i saw the example but in the field he was supposed to write the formula he didn't do it, so i don't know what formula it must be, i've tried with Record Sort Expert Property but it didn't change anything, i have no idea anymore what to do... The crystal always sort by the string instead of the field of DataBase...

Comment: I think he was referring to this formula: Totext ({Orders.Order Date}, 'MMM-yy')

Comment: But how this formula will help me because i want just the month and year ?

Comment: That's what it does, it formats the date field {Orders.Order Date} to display in a certain format (MMM-yy).

Comment: I've tried Totext ({Orders.Order Solicitacoes.Datames}, 'MMM-yy')        Totext ({Orders.Solicitacoes.Datames}, 'MMM-yy')                                Totext ({Orders.Order {Solicitacoes.Datames}}, 'MMM-yy')                        and all of them says "This name is not known" !

Comment: No, in your case it should be ToText({Solicitacoes.Datames}, 'MMM-yy')